# Rails - customizing asset path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have my Nginx configuration to serve assets from `http://<myhost>/custom_asset_path`.  Unfortunately I can not change that fact of life.

Is it possible to configure Sprockets to insert `custom_asset_path` into the asset URL?

I.e. I want my javascript_include_tag to generate something like:

```
<script src="/custom_asset_path/assets/application-ccfcccSHA_continues.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/638905/does-rails-4-asset-path-helper-uses-asset-prefix

Comment: When you mention "custom_assets_path", I presume this folder will be stored in the `public` dir?

Answer (score 1):

Set a custom path for `config.assets.prefix`:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path

Answer (score 0):

For want of an answer (I'd be interested to know this), I'd like to remind that  the assets path is simply in the `public` folder.

---

**Public**

When you direct requests through Nginx, you're actually sending them to the `public` folder of your app. When you precompile your assets, they end up in `public/assets`, although you only see `http://url.com/assets/`

Thus, if you want to make a custom folder for sprockets, you'll be able to use the suggestion from `@sean huber` -- `config.assets.prefix`:

> The public path that Sprockets uses by default is /assets.
>
> This can be changed to something else:
>   `config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"`

You must remember that any "prefix" you use should be to a member of the `public` directory, and thus you should expect it to be present there if you want it to work correctly.